# How to map XML to dynamic properties on an object in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, reflection, powershell, mapping

I need to automate the addition of many .NET objects to a business system. A PowerShell script needs to read an XML input file and perform the appropriate changes via the business system's API.

The problem I'm finding is that **the objects are of many different types and therefore have different properties**.

Here's an example of the XML:

```
<BusinessObject>
    <Action>Add</Action>
    <Id>{867B6C43-2A20-485D-A3E3-CBFCD50CA6F3}</Id>
    <AssemblyName>ABC.BusinessObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=361ad75badc53918</AssemblyName>
    <ClassName>ABC.BusinessObjects.HealthService</ClassName>
    <!-- Properties specific to object -->
    <HealthServiceName>Jo's GP Super Center</HealthServiceName>
</BusinessObject>
<BusinessObject>
    <Action>Add</Action>
    <Id>{867B6C43-2A20-485D-A3E3-CBFCD50CA6F3}</Id>
    <AssemblyName>ABC.BusinessObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=361ad75badc53918</AssemblyName>
    <ClassName>ABC.BusinessObjects.Patient</ClassName>
    <!-- Properties specific to object -->
    <PatientName>Anna Smith</PatientName>
</BusinessObject>
```

Relevant portion of script:

```
$xmlItem.BusinessObjects.GetElementsByTagName("BusinessObject") | % {
    $businessObject = $_
    if ($businessObject.Action -eq "Add") {
        $assemblyName = $businessObject.AssemblyName
        $className = $businessObject.ClassName
        $assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($assemblyName)
        $obj = $assembly.CreateInstance($className)
        ### TODO: How to set properties on $obj ???
        $api.AddBusinessObject($obj)
    }
}
```

I probably need to put the object-specific properties into their own XML element so that I can loop through them. What I'm not sure about is what to do inside that loop.

Assuming each property's XML element name matches the $obj property name, how do I dynamically access and set the property from its corresponding XML value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8235711/2495) using [`PropertyInfo.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue.aspx) will certainly work, but you can also take advantage of PowerShell's dynamic nature and automatic type conversion to greatly simplify the initialization:

```powershell
$businessObject.Properties.GetElementsByTagName( 'Property' ) | % {
  $obj.($_.Name) = $_.Value
}
```

Here, PowerShell will evaluate the `($_.Name)` value, and then invoke `$obj.___` with that value, just as if you had written `$obj.SomeProperty`. It will also convert the string returned by `$_.Value` to the appropriate type (as shown below)<sup>∗</sup>, whereas `SetValue` would throw an argument exception.

---

Combining with your existing code:

```powershell
$xmlItem.BusinessObjects.GetElementsByTagName( 'BusinessObject' ) | % {
  $businessObject = $_
  if( $businessObject.Action -eq 'Add' ) {
    $assemblyName = $businessObject.AssemblyName
    $className = $businessObject.ClassName
    $assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load( $assemblyName )
    $obj = $assembly.CreateInstance( $className )

    if( $businessObject.Properties ) {
      $businessObject.Properties.GetElementsByTagName( 'Property' ) | % {
        $obj.($_.Name) = $_.Value
      }
    }

    $obj  # $api.AddBusinessObject( $obj )
  }
}
```

I tested this using the following xml, adapted from the question's example ([AppDomainSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx) being a convenient system type with a lot of settable properties):

```xml
<BusinessObjects>
  <BusinessObject>
    <Action>Add</Action>
    <Id>{867B6C43-2A20-485D-A3E3-CBFCD50CA6F3}</Id>
    <AssemblyName>mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</AssemblyName>
    <ClassName>System.AppDomainSetup</ClassName>
    <Properties>
      <Property Name="DisallowCodeDownload" Value="True"/>
      <Property Name="LoaderOptimization" Value="SingleDomain"/>
      <Property Name="ConfigurationFile" Value="C:\config.xml"/>
    </Properties>
  </BusinessObject>
</BusinessObjects>
```

This sets the boolean `DisallowCodeDownload`<sup>∗</sup>, the enum `LoaderOptimization`, and the string `ConfigurationFile` properties to the specified non-default values.

---

**∗ Note:** One caveat to the simple approach is that the normal PowerShell scripting rules are used to convert boolean values, so only `$null`, `0`, and empty are treated as false, and everything else as true. This means a `Value="False"` setting in xml will *still* set the property to true, because PowerShell sees a non-empty string `'False'` and does not parse it further.

You *can* use an empty string, `Value=""`, to set a property to false. However, to allow the more intuitive parsing behavior, you would need to manually call [`[Convert]::ToBoolean( $_.Value )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean.aspx), or [`[Convert]::ChangeType( $_.Value, [bool] )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx), or something similar:

```powershell
$name = $_.Name
if( $obj.$name -is [bool] ) {
    $obj.$name = [Convert]::ToBoolean( $_.Value )
} else {
    $obj.$name = $_.Value
}
```

(Boolean properties usually have a default value of false, but I could see someone wanting explicit initialization, or toggling a single assignment by changing the value instead of deleting the entry, and running across this unexpected behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

I added a Properties element with Property child nodes to the XML and added this script:

```
if ($businessObject.Properties) {
    $businessObject.Properties.GetElementsByTagName("Property") | % {
        $prop = $_
        $pi = $obj.GetType().GetProperty($prop.Name)
        $pi.SetValue($obj, $prop.Value, $null)
    }
}
```